# Ubuntu 12.04 - Change rsyslog to use EDT|EST instead of UTC

Tags: time, rsyslog, timezone

Right now, I have rsyslog handling a log for a PHP app.  Well...I have PHP using rsyslog to do the logging.  Currently, it logs time in UTC.  I want it to log in EST/EDT as appropriate.  How do I make that change?

For the record, the timezone is set correctly in PHP and on the OS.  A point to note is that the OS is in a VM, although I don't know why that would make a difference as the host is also in EDT.

Answer (score 2):

syslog inherit time zone from the system so you should add desired TZ value to syslog process environment.

```
echo 'export TZ="EDT"' >> /etc/default/rsyslog
restart rsyslog
```

Comment: Tried that.  Still logging in UTC.

Comment: are you sure I've just tried an it works

Comment: this is my output https://gist.github.com/3452240

Comment: date() shows the correct time.  syslog does not.  In the log file its still printing time like this: [24-Aug-2012 15:35:56 UTC]

Comment: rsyslog actuialy doesn't print Time Zone in the log file. What is the name of the file  you are talking about ?